# My favorite drink or my best drink?

Tags: adjectives

I know that we say 'My best friend'. What is the difference between:

1. My favorite drink
2. My best drink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Favorite* usually means "the one that I like most", as in "Clam chowder is my favorite soup."  (That is, *Clam chowder is the soup that I like most.*)

*Best* usually means "highest in quality", as in "The French onion soup is their best."  (That is, *the French onion is their highest quality soup.*)

So *my favorite drink* is the drink that I like most.  *My best drink* is the highest-quality drink that I have.  You're right that *best friend* looks confusing in this context, but it's idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

I think I will say **"My favorite drink"** if I am telling someone about it. 
I think I will say **"My best drink"** if I made the drink myself and that's the one I can make very delicious or I am best at.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to food and drink, we typically say *my favorite*, but *the best*:

> Their lobster bisque is my favorite.
>   Their lobster bisque is the best!

When it comes to superlatives and people, though, employing a possessive pronoun is quite normal and idiomatic, particularly when describing some kind of personal relationship:

> Brian has been **my** best friend since childhood.
>   Michelle is **my** closest confidant at work.
>   David and Juanita are **their** closest neighbors.
>   Linda is **our** favorite stylist.
>   Ted is **his** biggest ally.